# Vertical timeline with inline css

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical timeline where I need the hexagons to be on the center line. My problem is, that I know it can be done with separate CSS sheet, but I have the order to use inline CSS, and the hexagons just can not be aligned. (I know this looks terrible, but this is what I have to do...)

The hexagons id is "marker".

Here is my code from codepen: https://codepen.io/thedude93/pen/ROWZRj

```
<div style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
            box-sizing: border-box; 
            outline: none;">
    <style>#container:before {content: '';
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0;
                            left: 50%;
                            margin-left: -1px;
                            width: 2px;
                            height: 100%;
                            background: #CCD1D9;
                            z-index: -1}</style>
    <div id="container" style="width: 80%;
                               padding: 50px 0;
                               margin: 50px auto;
                               position: relative;
                               overflow: hidden;">

        <div id="right" style="width: -webkit-calc(50% + 8px); 
                               width: -moz-calc(50% + 8px); 
                               width: calc(50% + 8px); 
                               display: -webkit-box; 
                               display: -webkit-flex; 
                               display: -moz-box; 
                               display: flex; 
                               -webkit-box-pack: justify; 
                               -webkit-justify-content: space-between; 
                               -moz-box-pack: justify; 
                               justify-content: space-between; 
                               clear: both; 
                               float: right">
            <div id="marker"><span style="color: #05bf85; 
                                        font-size: 30px;
                                        margin-left: auto;
                                        margin-right: auto">&#x2B22;</span></div>
                <div style=" width: 95%; 
                            padding: 0 15px; 
                            color: #666;">
                    <h3 style="margin-top: 5px; 
                               margin-bottom: 5px; 
                               font-size: 25px;
                               font-weight: 500">march 26.</h3>
                    <span style="font-size: 15px;
                                 color: #a4a4a4;"><a href="https://www.ispor.org/conferences-education/conferences/upcoming-conferences/ispor-warsaw-2019" target=_blank >ISPOR Warsaw 2019, Varsó, Lengyelország</a></span>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.5em; word-spacing: 1px;color: #888;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="left" style="width: -webkit-calc(50% + 8px); 
                              width: -moz-calc(50% + 8px); 
                              width: calc(50% + 8px); 
                              display: -webkit-box; 
                              display: -webkit-flex; 
                              display: -moz-box; 
                              display: flex; 
                              -webkit-box-pack: justify; 
                              -webkit-justify-content: space-between; 
                              -moz-box-pack: justify; 
                              justify-content: space-between; 
                              clear: both; 
                              float: left; 
                              transform: scaleX(-1)">
            <div id="marker"><span style="color: #05bf85; 
                                          font-size: 30px;
                                          ">&#x2B22;</span></div>
                <div style=" width: 95%; 
                            padding: 0 15px; 
                            color: #666; 
                            text-align:right; 
                            -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            transform: scale(-1, 1);">
                    <h3 style="margin-top: 5px; 
                               margin-bottom: 5px; 
                               font-size: 25px;
                               font-weight: 500">april 1.</h3>
                    <span style="font-size: 15px;
                                 color: #a4a4a4;"><a href="https://www.eunethta.eu/2019-eunethta-forum/" target=_blank >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></span>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px; 
                              line-height: 1.5em; 
                              word-spacing: 1px;
                              color: #888;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div id="right" style="width: -webkit-calc(50% + 8px); 
                               width: -moz-calc(50% + 8px); 
                               width: calc(50% + 8px); 
                               display: -webkit-box; 
                               display: -webkit-flex; 
                               display: -moz-box; 
                               display: flex; 
                               -webkit-box-pack: justify; 
                               -webkit-justify-content: space-between; 
                               -moz-box-pack: justify; 
                               justify-content: space-between; 
                               clear: both; 
                               float: right">
            <div id="marker"><span style="color: #05bf85; 
                                          font-size: 30px;
                                          ">&#x2B22;</span></div>
                <div style=" width: 95%; 
                            padding: 0 15px; 
                            color: #666;">
                    <h3 style="margin-top: 5px; 
                               margin-bottom: 5px; 
                               font-size: 25px;
                               font-weight: 500">april 4.</h3>
                    <span style="font-size: 15px;
                                 color: #a4a4a4;"><a href="https://meta2019.misandbos.hu/" target=_blank >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></span>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px; 
                              line-height: 1.5em; 
                              word-spacing: 1px;
                              color: #888;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                    </p>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div id="left" style="width: -webkit-calc(50% + 8px); 
                              width: -moz-calc(50% + 8px); 
                              width: calc(50% + 8px); 
                              display: -webkit-box; 
                              display: -webkit-flex; 
                              display: -moz-box; 
                              display: flex; 
                              -webkit-box-pack: justify; 
                              -webkit-justify-content: space-between; 
                              -moz-box-pack: justify; 
                              justify-content: space-between; 
                              clear: both; 
                              float: left; 
                              transform: scaleX(-1)">
            <div id="marker"><span style="color: #05bf85; 
                                          font-size: 30px;
                                          ">&#x2B22;</span></div>
                <div style=" width: 95%; 
                            padding: 0 15px; 
                            color: #666; 
                            text-align:right; 
                            -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            transform: scale(-1, 1);">
                    <h3 style="margin-top: 5px; 
                               margin-bottom: 5px; 
                               font-size: 25px;
                               font-weight: 500">june 4.</h3>
                    <span style="font-size: 15px;
                                 color: #a4a4a4;"><a href="https://www.htai2019.org/" target=_blank >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></span>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px; 
                              line-height: 1.5em; 
                              word-spacing: 1px;
                              color: #888;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS `width: calc(50% + 12px);` from `width: calc(50% + 8px);`

```html
<div style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
            box-sizing: border-box; 
            outline: none;">
    <style>#container:before {content: '';
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0;
                            left: 50%;
                            margin-left: -1px;
                            width: 2px;
                            height: 100%;
                            background: #CCD1D9;
                            z-index: -1}</style>
    <div id="container" style="width: 80%;
                               padding: 50px 0;
                               margin: 50px auto;
                               position: relative;
                               overflow: hidden;">

        <div id="right" style="width: -webkit-calc(50% + 12px); 
                               width: -moz-calc(50% + 12px); 
                               width: calc(50% + 12px); 
                               display: -webkit-box; 
                               display: -webkit-flex; 
                               display: -moz-box; 
                               display: flex; 
                               -webkit-box-pack: justify; 
                               -webkit-justify-content: space-between; 
                               -moz-box-pack: justify; 
                               justify-content: space-between; 
                               clear: both; 
                               float: right">
            <div id="marker"><span style="color: #05bf85; 
                                        font-size: 30px;
                                        margin-left: auto;
                                        margin-right: auto">&#x2B22;</span></div>
                <div style=" width: 95%; 
                            padding: 0 15px; 
                            color: #666;">
                    <h3 style="margin-top: 5px; 
                               margin-bottom: 5px; 
                               font-size: 25px;
                               font-weight: 500">march 26.</h3>
                    <span style="font-size: 15px;
                                 color: #a4a4a4;"><a href="https://www.ispor.org/conferences-education/conferences/upcoming-conferences/ispor-warsaw-2019" target=_blank >ISPOR Warsaw 2019, Varsó, Lengyelország</a></span>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.5em; word-spacing: 1px;color: #888;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="left" style="width: -webkit-calc(50% + 12px); 
                              width: -moz-calc(50% + 12px); 
                              width: calc(50% + 12px); 
                              display: -webkit-box; 
                              display: -webkit-flex; 
                              display: -moz-box; 
                              display: flex; 
                              -webkit-box-pack: justify; 
                              -webkit-justify-content: space-between; 
                              -moz-box-pack: justify; 
                              justify-content: space-between; 
                              clear: both; 
                              float: left; 
                              transform: scaleX(-1)">
            <div id="marker"><span style="color: #05bf85; 
                                          font-size: 30px;
                                          ">&#x2B22;</span></div>
                <div style=" width: 95%; 
                            padding: 0 15px; 
                            color: #666; 
                            text-align:right; 
                            -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            transform: scale(-1, 1);">
                    <h3 style="margin-top: 5px; 
                               margin-bottom: 5px; 
                               font-size: 25px;
                               font-weight: 500">april 1.</h3>
                    <span style="font-size: 15px;
                                 color: #a4a4a4;"><a href="https://www.eunethta.eu/2019-eunethta-forum/" target=_blank >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></span>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px; 
                              line-height: 1.5em; 
                              word-spacing: 1px;
                              color: #888;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div id="right" style="width: -webkit-calc(50% + 12px); 
                               width: -moz-calc(50% + 12px); 
                               width: calc(50% + 12px); 
                               display: -webkit-box; 
                               display: -webkit-flex; 
                               display: -moz-box; 
                               display: flex; 
                               -webkit-box-pack: justify; 
                               -webkit-justify-content: space-between; 
                               -moz-box-pack: justify; 
                               justify-content: space-between; 
                               clear: both; 
                               float: right">
            <div id="marker"><span style="color: #05bf85; 
                                          font-size: 30px;
                                          ">&#x2B22;</span></div>
                <div style=" width: 95%; 
                            padding: 0 15px; 
                            color: #666;">
                    <h3 style="margin-top: 5px; 
                               margin-bottom: 5px; 
                               font-size: 25px;
                               font-weight: 500">april 4.</h3>
                    <span style="font-size: 15px;
                                 color: #a4a4a4;"><a href="https://meta2019.misandbos.hu/" target=_blank >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></span>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px; 
                              line-height: 1.5em; 
                              word-spacing: 1px;
                              color: #888;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                    </p>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div id="left" style="width: -webkit-calc(50% + 12px); 
                              width: -moz-calc(50% + 12px); 
                              width: calc(50% + 12px); 
                              display: -webkit-box; 
                              display: -webkit-flex; 
                              display: -moz-box; 
                              display: flex; 
                              -webkit-box-pack: justify; 
                              -webkit-justify-content: space-between; 
                              -moz-box-pack: justify; 
                              justify-content: space-between; 
                              clear: both; 
                              float: left; 
                              transform: scaleX(-1)">
            <div id="marker"><span style="color: #05bf85; 
                                          font-size: 30px;
                                          ">&#x2B22;</span></div>
                <div style=" width: 95%; 
                            padding: 0 15px; 
                            color: #666; 
                            text-align:right; 
                            -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
                            transform: scale(-1, 1);">
                    <h3 style="margin-top: 5px; 
                               margin-bottom: 5px; 
                               font-size: 25px;
                               font-weight: 500">june 4.</h3>
                    <span style="font-size: 15px;
                                 color: #a4a4a4;"><a href="https://www.htai2019.org/" target=_blank >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></span>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px; 
                              line-height: 1.5em; 
                              word-spacing: 1px;
                              color: #888;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks, you solved it (I knew it will be something really easy:D)!

Comment: @TakácsBence Welcome Mate.